# Windows Portable Git integration to Portable Visual Studio Code: Which git.exe to use?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Unfortunately we can't install Git nor Visual Studio Code. Hence using "portable" versions of both. Looking for a smooth "bash" integration within VS-code in Windows 10

we have tried various combinations in the `git.path` and have added settings in user & workspace of VS-Code (as below)

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
    "git.enabled": true,
    "git.path": "C:\\installables\\PortableGit\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\installables\\PortableGit\\bin\\bash.exe"
}
```

The Git portable have git.exe in Various places as below.

```
./PortableGit/bin/git.exe
./PortableGit/cmd/git.exe
./PortableGit/mingw64/bin/git.exe
./PortableGit/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git.exe
./PortableGit/git-bash.exe
./PortableGit/git-cmd.exe
./PortableGit/mingw64/share/git/git-wrapper.exe
```

Not exactly sure, which of the "git*.exe" is required so the portable VS-code can integrate into its shell. Anyone had similar setup/settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`./PortableGit/bin/git.exe` is enough. I use it in combination of a portable VSCode without issue.

The other approach is to set the path correctly, then launch VSCode.

```
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

Comment: Thank you. The above \\PortableGit\\bin\\git.exe worked.
the `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` shows a deprecation warning. But hopefully will look into it later.